# How to find sum of a field in nested lists with a where condition?

Tags: list, lambda, nested

I am having two lists and I need to find sum of nested list and there should be filter on the first list.

Ex:

```
Class Customer{
    string Name
    List<Order> Orders
    string State
}

Class Order{
    int OrderID
    int OrderTotal
    int ItemCode
}
```

I need to find sum of Orders in a particular state, I am looking for a lambda expression for this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Below is the lambda expression with can be used to get the sum of the orderTotal with the filter on state.
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    Now add some data to your customer object and Order object.

```
customer.Where(cust => cust.State.Equals("Alaska")).Sum(order => order.OrderTotal);
```